# What's the proper way to align a strechable Text and an image to two ends in Unity UI?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an UI element that has a `Text` and an `Image` as its children. It has a `HorizontalLayoutGroup` component that enables `Control Child Size` and `Child Force Expand`.

I want the `Image` has a fixed size, and `Text` has strechable size controlled by the `HorizontalLayoutGroup`. So when the `Image` is set to inactive, the `Text` fills the whole space and when the `Image` is active, the `Text` shrinks a little bit in order to give space to the `Image`. Right now this part works good.

My second goal is to align them to both ends: the `Text` in the left and the `Image` on the right with space in between. But changing `Child Alignment` can't achieve this.

I tried the following solution:
Add `LayoutElement` both to `Image` and `Text`. On `Text`, enable `Flexible Width` and set a a value, on `Image`, enable `Min Width` and set to a value. Manually adjust the two values until it seems right.

This solution seems to work, but I don't know why. Is anyone familiar with this?What's the recommended way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out. On the `LayoutElement`, treat `Preferred Width` or `Preferred Height` as `Max Width` or `Max Height`. Enable them, set the value the same with min value. One the other objects that you want to stretch, enable `Flexible` values. Then all worked as we want.